# Do I get the benefit of the painting in Mudhold Fasting by using it or do I have to take it to Gravehal?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

There is a painting in Mudhold Fasting on Gallows End in the "Dead Kel" expansion of *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning*. Do I get the stat boost from the painting simply by interacting with it or do I need to somehow take it back to the Gravehal art gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that painting during the "Master of the Keep" quest after completely rebuilding Gravehal Keep. During the quest you will get petitions to do something, number 9 is find that painting.